# Why is DB::raw variable being amended from a string to an integer in Laravel 5.7

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have the following part of a larger elequent query, which all works when I'm not injecting a variable into DB::raw.

```
$tests->join('test_categories', function ($join) use($request) {
    $join->on('test_categories.id', '=', DB::raw('(select category_id
       from test_category
       join test_categories on test_category.category_id = test_categories.id
       where test_category.test_id = tests.id
       and test_categories.name = ?
       limit 1)', ['Cars']
    ));
});
```

But when the SQL executes it amends the '?' to 4, as in:

```
and test_categories.name = 4
```

Rather than being the expected:

```
and test_categories.name = 'Cars'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATED**

I also tried the following before:

```
$tests->join('test_categories', function ($join) use ($category) {
    $join->on('test_categories.id', '=', DB::raw("(select category_id
       from test_category
       join test_categories on test_category.category_id = test_categories.id
       where test_category.test_id = tests.id
       and test_categories.name = :category
       limit 1)",array('category' => $category)));
});
```

But in the query, this just outputs the following:

```
and test_categories.name = :category
```

This comes with a "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters" error.

Still the same issue.

And another variation which tries the same technique with the $join->on function.

```
$tests->join('test_categories', function ($join) use ($category) {
    $join->on('test_categories.id', '=', DB::raw("(select category_id
       from test_category
       join test_categories on test_category.category_id = test_categories.id
       where test_category.test_id = tests.id
       and test_categories.name = :category
       limit 1)"),array('category' => $category));
});
```

This results in an ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Array to string conversion:

```
protected function compileWheresToArray($query)
{
   return collect($query->wheres)->map(function ($where) use ($query) {
       return $where['boolean'].' '.$this->{"where{$where['type']}"}($query, $where);
        })->all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this link](https://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries) you could use

```php
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_col = :somevariable"), array(
   'somevariable' => $someVariable,
 ));
```

Comment: Thanks, @hoseinz3 I did try that technique as well. I can only imagine that it works within DB::select only and not the $join->on( I am using here. I've updated the question with the new findings, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `:category` with `".$category."`.

Not sure if it's a good practice to do it this way but it should work.

```
$tests->join('test_categories', function ($join) use ($category) {
    $join->on('test_categories.id', '=', DB::raw("(select category_id
       from test_category
       join test_categories on test_category.category_id = test_categories.id
       where test_category.test_id = tests.id
       and test_categories.name = ".$category."
       limit 1)"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a similar solution I have now, but it's not recommended as it could leave the code susceptible to SQL injection. Ideally, I'd like to use the built-in functions to handle this for increased security and best practice.